# MSB3021 not copy file -> access denied

Tags: c#, file, decompiling

I wnat to change some code in application. I decompose some libs and want to compile changed files. I have next csproj file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <AssemblyName>Siemens.Simatic.Hwcn.Basics</AssemblyName>
    <GenerateAssemblyInfo>False</GenerateAssemblyInfo>
    <UseWindowsForms>True</UseWindowsForms>
    <TargetFramework>net461</TargetFramework>
    <PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
    <UseCommonOutputDirectory>true</UseCommonOutputDirectory>
    <AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>false</AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>
    <AppendRuntimeIdentifierToOutputPath>false</AppendRuntimeIdentifierToOutputPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <LangVersion>7</LangVersion>
    <AllowUnsafeBlocks>True</AllowUnsafeBlocks>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <RootNamespace />
    <OutputPath>C:\Program Files\Siemens\Automation\Portal V15_1\Bin</OutputPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

And when I build solution display error:

Unable to copy file "obj\Debug\Siemens.Simatic.Hwcn.Basics.dll" в "C:\Program Files\Siemens\Automation\Portal V15_1\Bin\Siemens.Simatic.Hwcn.Basics.dll". The process cannot access the file "C:\Program Files\Siemens\Automation\Portal V15_1\Bin\Siemens.Simatic.Hwcn.Basics.dll".

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! There is a russian subdomain of stackoverflow, where you might find help faster: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/
Is your project cloned into `C:\Program Files`? That might be cause of the access denied error, have you tried a more public folder like `C:\MyProjects\`?

Comment: I have prorgamm. which install in Programm files yet. I tried to remove "read only" attribute for Siemens folder... I think not need remove this attribute for all Program Files, yaeh?

And sorry for russian text, it was a mistake

Comment: I would not recommend removing this attribute for all Program Files, no. But still, it might be an access problem, thats why i suggested movieng your project to a more public folder. My projects are und D:\Somewhere so i never run into those issues.
And don't worry, google translate helped ;)

Comment: Programs do not have write access to C:\Program Files.  Favor an OutputPath that's writeable or use Explorer to enable write access to the Bin folder.

Answer (score 0):

Just open Visual Studio with admin access